# Eliminar anteultimo nodo de una lista simplemente enlazada

Tags: python

Tengo que eliminar el anteúltimo nodo de una lista simplemente enlazada y mi código no funciona:

```
from lista import lista

lista1=lista()
lista1.insertar("hola")
lista1.insertar("anteultimo")
lista1.insertar("como estas")

def anteultimo(lista:lista):
    aux = lista.inicio

    if (aux.sig == None or aux == None):
        return ("Esta lista debe tener mas de 2 nodos para funcionar")

    while (aux != None):
        if (aux.sig.sig == None): ## No me anda esta linea por algun motivo
            print(aux.info)
        aux = aux.sig

anteultimo(lista1)
```

La clase lista que importé te da el atributo .inicio que indica cual es el primer nodo de la lista

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: ¿Para que se usaran las lista enlazadas en un lenguaje que tiene listas en forma nativa?

Comment: El profesor me pide que use listas enlazadas para practicar no es que lo hago porque tengo ganas nomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(aclaración: no tengo idea de python, así que puedo estar muy equivocado, ya me votaran negativo si es así)*

Esa línea que dices que no te anda, es porque en algún momento aux.sig es None y algo que es None no tiene siguiente (sig).

Misma razón por lo que debería dar vuelta el if

```
if (aux.sig == None or aux == None):
```

Primero se debería preguntar si aux==None y luego si es aux.sig == None, como tú lo tienes en el caso de una lista vacía daría error. Debería ser así

```
if (aux == None or aux.sig == None ):
```

Esta expresión se evalua de izquierda a derecha. Si aux es None ya entra al if sin necesidad de preguntar por aux.sig, que en el caso de una lista vacía daría error.

Luego te falta el caso de cuando la lista tiene solo 2 elementos, es decir cuando es primero y anteultimo a la vez.

Y también, en tu algoritmo debes recordar el previo, para enlazar este con el último.
Yo lo haría de esta manera:

```
def anteultimo(lista:lista):
    aux = lista.inicio

    if (aux == None or aux.sig == None ):
        print ("Esta lista debe tener mas de 2 nodos para funcionar")
        return
    elif (aux.sig.sig == None):  # vemos si solo son 2 elementos
        lista.inicio = aux.sig
        return

    while (aux.sig.sig != None): 
        prev = aux  # guardamos en anterior
        aux = aux.sig
    
    prev.sig = aux.sig  #enlazamos el anterior con el siguiente
```

Comment: A mi parecer, tu respuesta es correcta. Si algo esta mal, es probable que alguien de la comunidad te lo avise y corriga (no descarto lo de que si estubieras equivocado recibirias un voto negativo). Gracias por tu contribucion c: